# why is this php program getting error Undefined variabl

Tags: php

```
   <?php

$find = 'is';
$length = strlen($find);
$string = 'This is a string and is an example';


while($string_position = strpos($string,$find,$offset))
{
echo '<strong>'.$find. '</strong>'. ' found at '.$string_position.'<br>';
$offset = $string_position + $length;
 }

?>
```

Error message

> Undefined variable: offset in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\48StringPosition.php on line 10

Offset is defined by $ sign why i am getting this error

Comment: $offset is not defined before it is used. That is why it is undefined. What makes you think it is defined?

Comment: `$` doesn't ___define___ a variable, it ___identifies___ a variable... defining a variable means creating it and assigning it a value (even if that value is a null)

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to use `$offset` in your while loop conditional without initializing it first. You should add this `$offset = 0;` before your while loop.

Answer (score 1):

PHP cannot time travel:

```
while($string_position = strpos($string,$find,$offset))
                                              ^^^^^^^---using variable here

$offset = $string_position + $length;
^^^^^^---defined here, later on
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused about how variables are set

```
while($string_position = strpos($string,$find,$offset))
```

in this case `$offset` is not a definition, it's a reference. You're telling `strpos()` to use the data in `$offset` as an argument. A defintion looks like this

```
$offset = 1;
```

Note the use of `=`. That's how variables are defined

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
<?php
$find = 'is';
$length = strlen($find);
$string = 'This is a string and is an example';
$offset = 0; // Define offset to the first position of the string

while($string_position = strpos($string,$find,$offset))
{
    echo '<strong>'.$find. '</strong>'. ' found at '.$string_position.'<br>';
    $offset = $string_position + $length;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `strpos($string,$find,$offset)` without declaring $offset. you should initialize it before the while loop. For example `$offset = ''`

Answer (score -1):

You may pass an optional offset to `strpos`. That *needs* to be defined, though. The variable `$offset` isn't at the point of invocation of `strpos`.

Typically, for all "Undefined variable" errors, there is an attempt to read the *value* of a variable, before it's actually "declared". That's also the case in this loop of yours. It's passed to `strpos`, but it's defined within the loop body later.

```
$a = 5;
$sum = $a + $b;
//          ^
//          +---- This also is a read attempt of an undefined variable
```

Comment: I though when i wrote it down in the while loop with $ sign it got defined as a variable right at that moment, forgot to assign i t a value.

Comment: Correct. As mentioned above in a comment, `$` *refers* to a variable, but doesn't define it. It needs an initial value.